# Javascript pass array attribute as parameter

Tags: arrays, parameters, attributes

```
 var contact = { varWorkExperiences: [{ Experience: "aaa" },Experience: "bbb"}]  };
```

I have a structure like this. I can use push method like this:

```
contact.varWorkExperiences.push({ Experience: "ccc"});
```

but I want to do this paramaticly

I cant do this:

```
var x = "Experience";
contact.varWorkExperiences.push({ x: "ccc"});
```

How can I solve this? I have to use push method in function but I can't pass attribute as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var x = "Experience";
var obj = {};
obj[x] = "ccc";
contact.varWorkExperiences.push(obj);
```